# Qt Designer rearrangeable image grid

Tags: qt, user-interface

In Qt Designer, I would like to make a grid of rearrangeable tiles (or buttons) which users could sort by using a "drag and drop" gesture.

ex: a grid of 9x9 square tiles. the user can click tile #1 and "drag and drop" it to tile #9's position, while the other tiles rearrange themselves in a "snap to grid" manner, so that the grid always stays 9x9 but can be rearranged.

(kinda like a puzzle)

Hopefully this make sense.

I am a beginner and I am wondering if there is a widget for this. Or any way to do this at all?